# Qt Creator stuck repeating Android SDK cmdline-tools update via SDK Manager -- why?

Tags: android, qt, sdk, qt-creator

I am using Qt 5.15.1 with Qt Creator 8.0.2 on Windows 11, and configuring Android after downloading the JDK, SDK, and OpenSSL. The one step I am stuck on is with SDK Manager, which repeatedly requests to update one component of the SDK, the command line tool package. See the image below:

[Qt Creator Preferences->Devices->Android spontaneous dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiR8N.png)

I understand that the Android SDK directory for command line tools (C:/Android/SDK/cmdline-tools/ in my case) has a couple of files, bin/ and lib/ subdirectories, and a latest/ subdirectory which is getting updated when I accept the suggestion from the Qt Creator dialog. But doing so causes the newest content to be fetched from the server and installed to a *new* directory .../cmdline-tools/latest-**n**/, where **n** is a digit which increments with each repeated attempt. The explanation for the creation of each subdir is given by the dialog below, explaining that there was a prior latest/ already in existence.

[warning message from Android SDK command line tools update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY7iU.png)

But once that is done, Qt Creator's dialog for configuring Android settings (shown below) retains an error state due to a "missing package". I can click on SDK Manager tool button in Qt Creator to invoke it again, and it immediately presents the prompt shown in the first image.

[Qt Creator Preferences->Devices->Android dialog, showing incomplete configuration state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOxlV.png)

In the .../cmdline-tools/ directory, the file source.properties has this content:

`Pkg.Revision=9.0`

`Pkg.Path=cmdline-tools;9.0`

`Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Command-line Tools`

I looked around for a file that indicates whether the cmdline-tools package is at the latest revision, in the hopes that Qt Creator would look at that and conclude its configuration is complete. Did not find such a file.

I have tried renaming the newly installed latest-n/ subdir to latest/ and relaunching Creator. No change. I have tried removing the subdir latest/ outright (actually temporarily renaming it to .old), but then the SDK Manager fails to run from within Qt Creator (even though there is a .../cmdline-tools/bin directory with sdkmanager.bat in it.)

I have tried manually updating the SDK outside of Creator with:

`sdkmanager.bat --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`

in a bash window, and it produces the same message (on stdout) about not overwriting the original subdir, rather creating a numbered latest-n/ subdir.

I repeated all these attempts after adding paths to the .../cmdline-tools/latest/bin and .../cmdline-tools/bin directories to my system Path variable, as shown below. No benefit.

[Windows system environment variables, showing paths to the Android SDK tools at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w19Sk.png)

And finally, I tried ignoring this problem and moving on to configuring a Qt project for Android, but the option is not available because it claims that Android settings for Qt Creator are not complete.

Any suggestions out there?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem via a few steps, but unfortunately I am not sure which of them turned the key. So the following steps were sufficient for me, but not sure they were all necessary. I hope that one of more of them resolves the issue for others.

- switched from JDK 20 to JDK 17 (comment from @JoeCFD was apt) downloaded from Oracle here and pointed to it with a system environment variable JAVA_HOME = (in my case) C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
- switched from Qt 5.15.1 to 6.5, including porting some code due to library changes, well documented by Qt
- renamed my Android SDK directory to .old, effectively emptying it (and deleted the .old version later)
- let Android Studio version Electric Eel, installed previously, discover the missing SDK upon launch and perform the minimal downloads and configuration to get an SDK installed; under SDK Platforms tab: Android SDK platform 33 , and under SDK Tools tab: Android SDK command line tools (latest), Android Emulator, Android SDK Platform-Tools
- let Qt Creator then complete its required additions to the Android SDE/kit configuration via the usual Edit->Preferences->Devices->Android, having pointed at the JDK and SDK directories.

I am up and running now with Qt Android building and deploying into the Qt 6.5 Clang arm64-v8a architecture on a Pixel 5a target, and also running the same code on a Desktop PC configuration building with Qt 6.5 MSVC2019 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted *cmdline-tools* folder but keep other installed sdk stuff and restart QT Creator, then initiated Setup SDK again. It downloaded cmdline-tools once and happily said that everything is OK.
The folder *cmdline-tools* now contains only *latest* subfolder.
Try to delete everything else from *cmdline-tools* folder, or delete it completely and restart the setup.